# Regular Expression: Section names with unknown length?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text block that is formatted like this:

`1.2.3.4.5` or `1.2222.3.4.5` or `1` or `1.2`  etc

An unknow number of numbers and dots (sections of a legal document)

How can I capture the full section (1.2.3.4.5) into a group?

I use C# but any regex is fine, aI can translate it.

Comment: @downvoter(s): Stack-Overflow etiquette would have you leave a comment saying why you down-voted along with your down-vote.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv i did.  should i write a comment for every identical, but wrong answer i downvoted?

Comment: Somebody is going crazy with the downvotes here.

Comment: @SamIam At the time of my comment, (forgiving refreshing etc.) there were no such comments; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use this `Regex`:

```
Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d[\.\d]*(?<!\.)");
```

explain:

```
\d                       digits (0-9)

[.\d]*                   any character of: '.', digits (0-9) 
                         (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible))

(?<! subexpression)      Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.
```

Comment: You are missing a '('.  -->  @"([\d.]+)" worked when I tried it.

Comment: @GrayFox374: A new regex! tanks for attention

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "1.2.3.4.5 or 1.2222.3.4.5 or 1 or 1.2 or 2222.3333.111.5 etc";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+(\.\d+)*").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @SamIam It catches `2222.3333.111.5`

Comment: it seems as though it shouldn't  also `28359.205.295829.72827

Comment: @SamIam Have you read the question `An unknow number of numbers and dots`. and this is OP's sample `1.2222.3.4.5`

Comment: OP's sample always goes in order

Comment: @SamIam And you are sure this is a requirement. And downvote with an assumption?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13962/discussion-between-sam-i-am-and-l-b)

Answer (score 1):

well, if you know you can't go beyond 5, then you can do

```
@"1+((.2+)((.3+)((.4+)(.5+)?)?)?)?"
```

and you can expand on that pattern for every symbol, up to a finite number of symbols

the `+` means any number of occurrences of the symbol, but at least 1.  IF 0 is valid, you can use `*` instead

put `?:` after an opening parenthesies if you **don't** want the pattern to be captured
like example: `(?:abc)`
I ommitted them to make the regex more readable.

the ? after the parenthesies, means 1 or 0 of the preceding symbol.

Now if you don't know how far you string can go, for instance

`"1.2.3.4......252525.262626.272727.......n.n.n"` than my intuition tells me that you can't do that with regex.

Comment: Accepted answer shows that you made a wrong assumption about ordering.

Comment: @L.B  I did upvote all the answers where my vote was not locked